# Jquery $(this) returns object with incorrect attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form, it is rendered in the html as:

```
<form action="/Home/SimpleSearch" id="searchForm" .....>
```

I can confirm with Chrome dev tools that `$('form[id=searchForm]').attr('action')` returns:

```
"/Home/SimpleSearch"
```

I have JavaScript wired up to capture the submit event:

```
$('form[id=searchForm]').submit(function () { 
    var $form = $(this); 
    ....
}
```

However, when I look at the action attribute of $form it is incorrect. It is `"/Home/Search"` instead of `"/Home/SimpleSearch"`

I do have a "search" action located at "/Home/Search" and I recently switched my code to use "/Home/SimpleSearch"... does $(this) get cached somewhere or something?

Comment: What does `$('form[id=searchForm]').length` give you? if it isn't 1, you're doing it wrong. id's must be unique, but aren't in your case.

Comment: $('form[id=searchForm]').length returns 1

This id is unique

Comment: then i won't be able to reproduce your problem. Something is likely changing the action property programmatically, which doesn't always display in the dom inspector.

Comment: I second with Kevin B, i am unable to reproduce the problem either. I get `/Home/SimpleSearch` when retrieving the action name.

Comment: in this case updating the this particular property does update the attribute, so there's no reason it shouldn't have matched the dom inspector.

Comment: Very very odd. After re-debugging multiple times it kept giving me the same results. Finally closing VS and my browser worked....
Not sure what happened there